# Android Back-to-Back Dialogs are not Properly Dismissed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I need some help with a problem I'm having with DialogFragments in an Android app. I've been stuck for too long. I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly, but I don't know what. The best way for me to explain the problem is with a minimal example:

#### MainActivity.java

Our main activity has a button that shows a dialog.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDialogFragment(DialogFragment fragment) {
        // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
        // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
        // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Show the dialog.
        fragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    }

    public void showDialogA(View v) {
        showDialogFragment(new DialogFragmentA());
    }
}
```

#### DialogFragmentA.java

DialogFragmentA is a simple dialog with two buttons. One button cancels, the other shows DialogFragmentB.

```
public class DialogFragmentA extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Dialog A")
                .setTitle("Dialog A")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this)
                .setPositiveButton("Go to B", this)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        if (i == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
            dismiss();
        } else if (i == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            dismiss();
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showDialogFragment(new DialogFragmentB());
        }
    }
}
```

#### DialogFragmentB.java

DialogFragmentB is similar. One button takes you back to A.

```
public class DialogFragmentB extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Dialog B")
                .setMessage("Dialog B")
                .setPositiveButton("Do Something", this)
                .setNegativeButton("Go to A", this)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        if (i == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
            dismiss();
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showDialogFragment(new DialogFragmentA());
        } else if (i == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem I'm having is that if I go from one dialog to the next, the original dialog is not properly dismissed. For example, from MainActivity:

1. Click "Show Dialog A".
2. Click "Go to B".
3. Click "Do something". This should close *all* dialogs. But in fact takes you back to dialog A.

There are many other ways to produce similar behavior. I'm sure I've implemented something incorrectly or I'm doing something that's not allowed, but I don't know what or how to fix it. If you want to experiment, I can provide a Github repository with the code from above.

Comment: I don't think you are handling the fragment stack correctly when creating new dialog fragments. Take another look at the DialogFragment lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: That's it! Awesome! Apparently I took my showDialog() method from the "Basic Dialog" section of the page you linked, but I should have taken it from the "Alert Dialog" Section further down. My new showDialogFragment method is a one-liner that looks like this: `fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");`. All behavior oddities are gone! If you want to write up your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Right on! Thanks, but I just guided you in the right direction. You found the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As DigitalNinja pointed out, there was a problem with the way I was creating new dialog fragments. Specifically, most of what I was doing in MainActivity.showDialogFragment() (above) was either unnecessary or wrong.

This revised version of MainActivity.showDialogFragment() fixes all the problems I was having:

```
public void showDialogFragment(DialogFragment fragment) {
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```